# laravel route work wrong to direct to views

Tags: php, laravel

I am a new laraveler, now I work with a  problem  about laravel.  I want the `/` direct to a anguler `index.html`.  and others route to laravel controller.  but when the `\` direct well . the others routes work wrong to a `views` directory.
   the `\app\Http\route.php` like follows :

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return File::get(public_path().('/views/index.html'));
});

Route::get('scan', "userController@Scan");
Route::get('check', "userController@Check");
Route::get('login', "userController@Login");
```

the directy is something like follows:

`├── app
│   ├── Http
│   │   ├── route.php          //route file
│   ├── Library
│   ├── Providers
│   ├── Services
│   ├── User.php
│   └── views

│   │   ├── Index.php           // php   index  file  ,   the   entry  for  nginx  server
│   └──  ..........
├── bootstrap
│   ├── app.php
│   ├── autoload.php
│   └── cache
├── config
│   ├── app.php
│   └── view.php
│   └──  ..........
├── public
│   ├── bower_components
│   ├── css
│   ├── data
│   ├── index.bak
│   ├── index.html              //angular  index  file
│   └── scripts
│   └──  ..........`

now when I access to  http://hostname/scan  it comes 404 no found.

and the log like follows:
```
 *2221 open() "/service/angular-laravel/app/views/scan" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: hostname, request: "GET /scan HTTP/1.1", host: "banliyun.com:8081"

```

as I was a little confuse with how the route work.  can someone tell me why  it will route to /views  directory  where  place the laravel  index  page.

Answer (score 1):

Save your `index.html` as `index.blade.php` in `/resources/views/index.blade.php` and you change your route to the following code:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
  return view('index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In **`AppServiceProvider`** class **boot** method add below line:

```
View::addLocation(public_path('views'));
```

Rename `index.html` file as `index.blade.php` and then follow below line in your `route.php`

```
 Route::get('/', function(){
  return view('index');
 });
```